# Passing instance as object and getClass() returns java.lang.Class

Tags: java, class, object, reflection

I'm trying to get the class name of a passed Object. However the Object#getClass() just returns java.lang.Class. Here is an example where obj is an instance of `net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.IChatBaseComponent`:

```
System.out.println("logging x2: " + obj.getClass()); // class java.lang.Class
```

Why is this happening, and how can I get around it. No I cannot use `newInstance` or `instanceof` or `isAssignableFrom` because the entire method is used to determine the class names of passed objects.

The full methods looks like this:

```
public Method getMethod(String name, Class<?>... paramTypes) throws Exception {
    Class<?>[] types = toPrimitiveTypeArray(paramTypes, false);

    for (Method method : this.getClazz().getMethods()) {
        Class<?>[] methodTypes = toPrimitiveTypeArray(method.getParameterTypes(), true); // here is where it logs

        if (method.getName().equals(name) && isEqualsTypeArray(methodTypes, types)) {
            method.setAccessible(true);
            return method;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(StringUtil.format("The method {0} was not found with parameters {1}!", name, Arrays.asList(types)));
    return null;
}

private static Class<?>[] toPrimitiveTypeArray(Object[] objects, boolean log) {
    Class<?>[] types = new Class<?>[objects != null ? objects.length : 0];

    for (int i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
        if (log) System.out.println("logging x1: " + objects[i]); // interface net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.IChatBaseComponent
        if (log) System.out.println("logging x2: " + objects[i].getClass()); // class java.lang.Class
        if (log) System.out.println("logging x3: " + objects[i].getClass().getName()); // java.lang.Class
        types[i] = getPrimitiveType(objects[i].getClass()); // This just swaps out primitives for their class-versions, or returns the passed class, the problem happens before this
    }

    return types;
}
```

Comment: Just returns `java.lang.Class`;

Comment: How are you using this method?

Comment: Clearly `objects` contains instances of `java.lang.Class`. I don't really see what the problem is.

Comment: @Radiodef I was thinking `getPrimitiveType(objects[i].getClass())` may recurse and have the same practical effect.

Comment: I added how the method is called.

Comment: `Class#getClass()`...what do you expect it to return?

Comment: I expect the name of the object, how can I get it? getClass() of the passed object should be returning the class of the object..

Comment: Objects don't have names.

Comment: I want the name of its instance then.. jesus I want the line that results in the interface, how can I get that?

Comment: Try using `Class#getSimpleName` or `Class#getTypeName`

Comment: _name of its instance_ Again, that's not something that exists. Please be more clear. I don't understand what you mean by _the line that results in the interface_

Comment: What does `getPrimitiveType` expect as an argument?

Comment: A class, since it's just changing byte to Byte, int to Integer, etc. That's all it does. The problem is happening before that line so I don't know why you ask

Comment: If `obj.getClass()` is printing out `class java.lang.Class`, then `obj` is definitely not an instance of `IChatBaseComponent`. It is an instance of the type `Class` representing the type `IChatBaseComponent`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis How can I know if it's an instance of type class and not an object?

Comment: `getClass` returns an instance of type `Class` representing the type of the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is what you want.

```
private static Class<?>[] toPrimitiveTypeArray(
//      vvvvvvvv
        Class<?>[] objects, boolean log) {
    ...

    for (int i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
        ...
        //                          vvvvvvvvvv
        types[i] = getPrimitiveType(objects[i]);
    }
    ...
}
```

`getParameterTypes` already returns an array of `Class` which you were implicitly upcasting to `Object`.

Or possibly you want to do `getPrimitiveType(objects[i].getName())` which you could do now. (But your description is not clear to me so I can't say for sure.)

Comment: How can I know if the object is just `Class<?>` and not something inheriting class? Because the method is used by actual Object instances.

Comment: `java.lang.Class` is final so a class cannot inherit from it. I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Thanks! The solution was to add a second toPrimiteTypesArray that took `Class<?> objects` instead.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to get the class name of a passed Object

```
    private static void toPrimitiveTypeArray(Object[] objects, boolean log) {
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(objects[i].getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
```

If you want to just return all the Class name of classes in Object array.

Answer (score -2):

`objects[i].getClass().getName()` should work.